# EditText in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm using a BroadcastReceiver to receive a Notification at a given time. Now I trying to get the Input from a EditText into that Status Bar Notification. I tried it now with a LayoutInflater but I just can't get it to work.

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    notificationStatus(context);
}

private void notificationStatus(Context context) {
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    EditText etxt_title = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.etxt_title);
    String n_title = etxt_title.getText().toString();

    EditText etxt_message = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.etxt_message);
    String n_message = etxt_message.getText().toString();

    final long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, n_title + " - " + n_message, when);
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context
            .getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context
            .getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, n_title, n_message,
            contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}}
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work like this? The output I'm getting is just empty, no error.

Comment: Have you tried printing `n_message` and `n_title` to a log to see if they contain the information you thing they should? At a glance it seems you are setting them correctly in `notification.setLatestEventInfo()`.

Comment: Yes, I already tried but the output is just empty! And in the notification I can only see the " - " that I set between n_title and n_message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using a BroadcastReceiver to receive a Notification at a given time.

That sentence does not make any sense. `BroadcastReceivers` do not "receive a Notification" at all.

> Now I trying to get the Input from a EditText into that Status Bar Notification.

Your `EditText` needs to be in an activity. You do not have an activity.

> I tried it now with a LayoutInflater but I just can't get it to work.

First, a `BroadcastReceiver` has no user interface.

Second, just because you inflate a layout with `LayoutInflater`, that does not mean that the layout actually appears on the screen. For that, you need an activity.

Comment: 1. Yeah I wrote that a bit wrong. I'm using the AlarmManager to display the Notification at a given Time.

2. My EditText is in a activity. But I want to get the Input from the user from that activity into my Notification, which is triggered by the BroadcastReceiver

3. I know that, I only use the BroadcastReceiver to trigger the Notification.

Comment: @cTrox: Have the activity display the `Notification`. Or, have the activity save the text to a database or file, and have the `BroadcastReceiver` start an `IntentService` that will read the database or file and display the `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have same issue in Widget broadcast receiver. I can not inflate any thing there. I wanna inflate new complicated view then update it and then export it as image and finally update my remote view image.

Comment: @Mahdi: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] showing what you are trying and explaining what your results are.